# Create Powershell content with a paragraph of text

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that creates a 'file' (no extension) containing our VPN connection configuration.
The VPN app we're using (AWS) creates a 'file' using the relevant connection information in the user profile - so I'm simply trying to replicate that information by creating the file from scratch.

Example of the file I'm trying to create

client

dev tun

proto udp

INFORMATION

INFORMATION

So far, this is working

```
$config = @'

client

dev tun

proto udp

INFORMATION

INFORMATION

'@

$config > "C:\users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\AWSVPNClient\OpenVpnConfigs\AWS VPN Tech"
```

This creates the exact file (letter for letter) and seems to keep the paragraph format.

However, my new file is 10KB, and the original file I copied/pasted from is only 5KB.
The connection fails also. Whilst it appears to be creating a replica, it's clearly not.

I'm guessing this is some sort of encoding issue. Not sure where to start really. There's not much information I can find out on the original file as to what the format is. Windows just sees it as a 'file' (no extension).

I'm using Notepad++ to create my scripts and so far, haven't had any issues up until now.

Comment: Use `Set-Content` instead of `>`: `$config |Set-Content "C:\users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\AWSVPNClient\OpenVpnConfigs\AWS VPN Tech"
`

Comment: Thank you Mathias that has worked. Appreciate the help. I knew about Set-Content, just didn't know how to piece it together.

Answer (score 0):

The stream redirection operators (`>` and `>>`) defaults to calling `Out-File -Encoding Unicode` when used against the file system provider.

Instead, use the `Set-Content` cmdlet, it defaults to UTF8:

```
$config |Set-Content "C:\users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\AWSVPNClient\OpenVpnConfigs\AWS VPN Tech"
```